# Android - new Interstitial Ad not Loading (Admob)

Tags: android, admob, loading, ads, interstitial

I'm trying to test interstitial ads in my app, and the first interstitial works fine. However, when I request a new, second ad using `mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build())`, onAdLoaded() is never called.

My AdListener, if it helps:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            adIsLoaded = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

            adIsLoaded = false;
            adIsTimeReady = false;

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            new CountDownTimer(adInterval, adInterval) { //timer to only show new ad if atleast some interval of time has passed

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

                public void onFinish() {
                    adIsTimeReady = true;
                }
            }.start();
```

I am using an emulator, so the ads are test ads. Is there only one test ad or something, and a new ad can't be requested?

Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue was that I was trying to load a new ad before the previous one was closed. Below I simply deleted the onAdOpened method and moved its contents to the onAdClosed method.

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            adIsLoaded = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {

            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

            adIsLoaded = false;
            adIsTimeReady = false;

            new CountDownTimer(adInterval, adInterval) {

                public void onTick(long adInterval) {}

                public void onFinish() {
                    adIsTimeReady = true;
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```